# Ripple Noise Using Capture CIS and PSpice

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, ripple, orcad

I am trying to measure the ripple output noise of a regulator using simulation on Orcad CIS and PSpice. The output voltage and current are correct however the transient time response is not showing any relation to the output ripple.
Below is my circuit:
[image]

And here is the transient response of the circuit:
[image]
My question is: Is there a way to show the ripple noise on the graph or any other interface in PSpice?

Comment: Transient output graph extends to only 10 nanoseconds. If this switcher is switching 2.5 MHz, can you try extending time to a microsecond or two?

Comment: Still same result, a straight line

Comment: Is **EN** pin (4) above 1V?

Comment: Yes I connect it to VIN (pin 9)